# HMI object template creation in TwinCAT 3.0 HMI

Tags: automation, plc, twincat-hmi

I'm just discovering TwinCAT 3 software and would like to realize a PLC + HMI application using it.
PLC is quite clear but concerning HMI, I went through several tutorials and found how to add some meters and buttons on a page but I would like to create some kind of generic visual object that could be reused (lets says instantiated) in order to match a PLC object with a predefined data structure.
As an example, I have in my PLC a Function Block with some variable like "Description" and "Value"
I have in my "main" code several instances of this function block, let s call them AnalogSensor1 and AnalogSensor2
In my HMI, I know how to add a text box and a displayer in order to display "Description" and "Value" PLC values but as I have plenty of values and plenty of instance fo my Fuuntion block, I would like to avoid connecting them one by one and rather to be able to create a template of my HMI object (made from a text box and a value box) and link them to a fake variable like MyObject.Description and MyObject.Value
Then the idea would be to drag and drop this object template and map it not on the value itself but to the AnalogSensor1 or AnalogSensor2 instances (MyObject = AnalogSensor1 and automatically it will map AnalogSensor1.Description in my text box). This idea being to have one connection per function block rather than one connection per data to display.

I tried to read the Twincat official documentation and searched the web but can't find any answer to this

Does someone know if this is something achievable in TwinCAT 3 and if yes could you point me to some tuto or examples somewhere to help me to realize this ?

Thanks in advance to the community
Francois